# Codename one gui builder does not work

Tags: codenameone, gui-builder

I am trying to use code name one new GUI designer tool.
Version - Codename one GUI builder 3.7.3
Eclipse - Used Oxygen and Mars both.
Java - tried 7 and 8 both.

My problem is i cannot add any containers or any component to the design area. Once i add one it suddenly disappear. ( Simply cannot create any UI)
I cannot change the layout even.Always it shows Layered layout and cannot change.

I have created a java 7 as well as java 8 code name projects but nothing works.

I followed - https://www.codenameone.com/blog/using-the-new-gui-builder.html
According to tutorial 
Figure 14. The features of the main toolbar 
In my editor i don't see 'Component tree icon'.

Also i cannot generate codes such as
//-- DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE!!!
    private void initGuiBuilderComponents(com.codename1.ui.util.Resources resourceObjectInstance) {
    }
//-- DON'T EDIT ABOVE THIS LINE!!!
}
Do i miss anything ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't support Java 7 so make sure your JDK is a Java 8 JDK and the one eclipse is running on top is a Java 8+ JDK.

Make sure you created the GUI component under a package and didn't refactor it after the fact. You can also read about debugging and tracking issues in the designer/gui builder in [this article](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-track-designer-guibuilder-issues.html).

Comment: I have checked your points. Java version for pc and eclipse are both same and its java 1.8 update 51. But i cannot use the builder. It opens without any error and add components too. But just after add components it is not visible. There is a message saying no component selected in left lower corner widget.

Comment: Check out this tip: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-track-designer-guibuilder-issues.html try running the GUI builder from the command line and see if there are errors in the log.